# BusyBox: How can I replace the imple function of udev with mdev?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, udev, busybox

I run a smart Embedded Linux on a board and I want to create device files, for that I need udev. But Udev needs alot of other small programs or libs. So the question is:

**How can I replace the imple function of udev with mdev?**

Answer (score 1):

`mdev` is part of the `busybox`. You can recompile the busybox and install it to your root filesystem, also remove your `udev` files from the root filesystem

You can follow this [thread](http://blackfin.uclinux.org/gf/project/uclinux-dist/forum/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=39605&action=ForumBrowse) to configure and write your custom `mdev` rule.

Thanks

Comment: another good post for mdev turtorial http://quirk.ch/2010/01/how-to-set-up-mdev-rules-for-busybox